# Qual a aplicabilidade prática da palavra super em Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Há várias explicações na internet afora a respeito. Mas ainda não consegui entender qual é a aplicabilidade prática da palavra **super** em ruby. Tá, sei que ela serve pra chamar o método com mesmo nome na superclasse. Certo. Mas e aí, por que eu iria querer fazer isso? Tenho menos de um ano de trabalho na área, então ainda não vi essa palavra ser usada na prática. Alguém poderia dar um exemplo ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Trabalhei pouco com Ruby, mas em Java e AS3 uma situação que se faz necessária, quando criamos um construtor na classe "filha", necessitamos executar o construtor da classe "pai", por exemplo uma classe (pai) para conexão com uma base de dados geralmente abre a conexão no construtor, para que a conexão seja aberta na classe filha é necessário chamar o `super`. Acredito que seja equivalente no Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há muitas situações onde é necessário estender determinada funcionalidade de uma classe existente. Podem haver várias especializações de um determinado comportamento.

Claro, isso pode ser feito simplesmente alterando-se a classe original, talvez colocando um `if` para cada nova situação que surgir.

Porém isso não é uma boa prática do ponto de vista de modelagem. O código vai ficando confuso e a chance de aparecerem novos erros é grande.

Num modelo de classes ideal você nunca precisaria alterar uma classe existente para acrescentar uma nova funcionalidade ou comportamento mais específico. Bastaria estender uma classe.

Embora existam vários exemplos práticos, nem todos funcionam fora de contexto. Vou trabalhar com alguns abaixo.

## Exemplo prático de construtor

Suponha que você tem a classe `Pessoa`:

```rb
class Pessoa
    def initialize(nome)  
        @nome = validarNome(nome)
    end
    def validarNome(nome)
        ...
    end
end
```

E agora uma especialização `PessoaFisica`:

```rb
class PessoaFisica < Pessoa
    def initialize(nome, cpf)  
        super(nome)
        @cpf = validarCpf(cpf)
    end
    def validarCpf(cpf)
        ...
    end
end
```

E mais um nível de especialização `Funcionario`:

```rb
class Funcionario < PessoaFisica
    def initialize(nome, cpf, pis)  
        super(nome, cpf)
        @pis = validarPis(pis)
    end
    def validarPis(pis)
        ...
    end
end
```

Nos exemplos acima, o construtor da superclasse cuida da validação do atributo que ela possui.

As subclasses acrescentam novos atributos e invocam o construtor da respectiva superclasse delegando a inicialização e validação dos atributos herdados.

Esta é uma forma de manter a funcionalidade existente, acrescentar novas funcionalidades e garantir o correto comportamento do programa reusando o que já existe, sem duplicar código.

## Exemplo de método "decorativo"

Imagine que você tem uma classe que retorna uma mensagem:

```rb
class GeradorMensagem
    def getMensagem
        "Olá mundo!"
    end
end
```

Agora você precisa criar uma especialização desta mensagem para exibição em uma página web. Poderia fazer algo como:

```rb
class GeradorMensagemHtml < GeradorMensagem
    def getMensagem
        "<div>" + super + "</div>"
    end
end
```

## Exemplo de comportamento especializado

Dada uma classe `Cliente` assim:

```rb
class Cliente
    def limiteCredito
      #consulta limite de crédito
    end
end
```

Pode haver um `ClienteEspecial` que, além do limite normal, possui um valor especial. O limite então seria a soma de ambos. Vejamos como isso pode ser implementado com reuso:

```rb
class ClienteEspecial < Cliente
    def limiteCreditoEspecial
        #consulta limite de crédito especial
    end
    def saldo
        limiteCredito + limiteCreditoEspecial
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Redefinindo, sobrescrevendo e *super*

- **Redefinindo Métodos**

Redefinir um método consiste em substituir um método por outro. E o método original, simplesmente, se perde.

Exemplo:

```
class Rectangle
  def initialize(length, breadth)
    @length = length
    @breadth = breadth
  end

  def perimeter
    2 * (@length + @breadth)
  end

  def area
    @length * @breadth
  end
end
```

Quando invocados os métodos **area** e **perimeter** teremos, respectivamente, **20** e **18**.

Mas se quebrarmos a classe *Rectangle* definindo esses mesmos métodos mas sem implementá-los:

```
class Rectangle
  def perimeter
  end

  def area
  end
end
```

Os testes falham.

E porque quase todos os métodos do Ruby podem ser redefinidos, deve-se tomar bastante cuidado especialmente com classes-base como Object, Array e etc já que uma redefinição impensada pode quebrar a Aplicação inteira, então, como regra geral:

> Nunca redefinda métodos, especialmente se estes forem definidos pela linguagem. Mesmo!

- **Sobrescrevendo Métodos**

Sobrescrever, no contexto de uma classe consiste em definir um método em uma subclasse que já exista na superclasse, sem prejuízo de afetar a implementação original dela.

Exemplo:

```
class MyArray < Array 
  def map
    'in soviet russia...'
  end
end
```

No exemplo acima criamos uma subclasse *MyArray*, derivando de [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html), e sobrescrevemos o método [Array.map()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map).

Ao testar esse código, com ambos os objetos, veremos que apenas o comportamento de *MyArray.map* é prejudicado, ficando o original intacto e plenamente funcional.

- **Super Powered**

O uso mais comum de herança é sobrescrever métodos de uma classe para que este faça alguma coisa **a mais** que sua contraparte na superclasse, ao invés de sobrescrevê-lo por inteiro para fazer outra coisa completamente diferente (como nos exemplos acima)

Isso nos permite reutilizar o comportamento que já existe na superclasse e então modificá-lo para se adequar as necessidades da subclasse.

A maioria das linguagens Orientada a Objetos oferecem um meio de um método sobrescrito poder invocar o método em substituição. Em Ruby isso se dá através da palavra-chave **super**.

Ao usar **super** o método invocará sua contraparte de mesmo nome, mas a partir do contexto da superclasse.

Exemplo:

```
class Animal
  def move
    "I can move"
  end
end

class Bird < Animal
  def move
    super + " by flying"
  end
end

puts Animal.new.move
puts Bird.new.move
```

No exemplo acima definimo o comportamento de uma classe *Animal* que descreve como ele se move. Um pássaro também é um animal e por derivar a classe *Bird* de *Animal* dizemos que todos os pássaros também se movimentam.

Mas pássaros se movimentam de um jeito diferente, voando, então alteramos o comportamento de *Bird.move* invocando **move** no contexto da superclasse, complementando, assim, a característica de que pássaros se movem voando.

Fonte: [RubyMonk](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/37-classes-inheritance/lessons/88-redefining-overriding-and-super#solution4090)

Comment: Muito bom Bruno, muito importante mesmo a dica sobre "Nunca redefina métodos" +1

Comment: E apesar de ser algo escrito para Ruby, é uma regra que acredito seja válida para  todas as linguagens, pelo menos de alto nível. Se algo foi concebido para fazer X, não o imeça de fazer X. Derivee faça XX. Derivar te restringe? [Adapte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Comment: Entendi, realmente faz todo sentido, realmente deve ser válido para qualquer linguagem. Talvez vale mesclar isto a resposta.